# GRAV Unable to find grav-plugin-editable

Tags: php, plugins, content-management-system, contenteditable, grav

I'm working on GRAV in order to offer a user friendly UX to edit the content.
I found some nice plugins, but i cant find the coolest of them :
**GRAV-PLUGIN-EDITABLE**
which allow user to edit directly in the front-end views of the site with content-editable-like feature (differs to the nice https://github.com/bleutzinn/grav-plugin-editable-simplemde

It looks like that you can see on the vidéo linked below, and this is the only clue that i have

[The Video of the plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8MAdLwV0fE)

I hope someone could help me to find that hidden plugin :)

Comment: Looks like you figured it out on your own... Care to self answer to help people who may have a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a lot of search, and I think I've finished my quest :

I've contacted the author on github, and he explains publicly the reasons why this nice project have been stopped . I authorize myself to publish here a part of his response as it is in a public thread he response to me :

> The reason for removing the repository is that Grav uses Markdown for content and the editor ContentTools can't work with Markdown. ContentTools requires content to be stored in HTML. Grav can do that too, so that is why it all was working fine.
>   The problem was in that many people were very confused about the switch from Markdown to HTML when using Grav. All Grav documentation focuses on Markdown which becomes useless when you switch to HTML.
>   Also I could not get an image upload function working from the ContentTools editor, which is, I think, required.
>   I agree that ContentTools offers a very nice user experience and I would love to see it back with Grav.

**to see the integrality of our conversation and if the link he's gave inside is always valid, download the content of his plugin :** [click here](https://github.com/bleutzinn/grav-plugin-editable-simplemde/issues/7)